# Where to find AWS Amplify Logger logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-amplify

Im currently working on a WebApp created with AWS Amplify, where I have to implement logging.
Based on the [AWS Amplify Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/logger/q/platform/js) there is a built in Logger function, which i tried to implement, but cant seem to find it anywhere in my AWS console.

Does anybody know where to find the logs?

Comment: Cloudwatch logs

Comment: That is my issue, it does not appear in the cloudwatch logs, so i was wondering if it was logged somewhere else?

Comment: where you run the application? ec2, lambda?

Comment: Thats a great question, I am testing it locally on my react app, but not sure if that should affect the logging?

Comment: ic. That's the document you can follow up: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-premise.html

Comment: @dev.tom- did you found the solution to this? - Did you checked the browser console?

Comment: Same question for me. When I go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logsV2:home and click "View Log Groups" I see many that contains /lambda/amplify.  I'm guessing one of those has it, but I don't know which one, or how to search all of them at once.

Comment: @NealWalters its been a while since I worked on this project/issue, but from what I can remember, I think we ended up with just using regular 'console.log' in our lambdas, and it would show up in the log groups for that specific lambda function. hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add another solution.

Yes, you can see them in AWS Cloudwatch Logs, but you need a bit of configuration.

[Here the PR](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/8309) which introduced the feature.
You already have everything installed if you get the latest Amplify version (quite everything for React Native users, see later).

Setup the add-on:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Logging: {
    logGroupName: '<loggroup-name>',
    logStreamName: '<logstream-name>',
    region: '<region-code>',
  },
  ...awsconfig,
});

const logger = new Logger('yourloggername', 'DEBUG');
Amplify.register(logger);
logger.addPluggable(new AWSCloudWatchProvider());
```

Now you can log to cloudwatch:

```
logger.debug('hello logging');
```

You need to configure IAM in AWS, I report a working example for simplicity.
Add this policy to the IAM identity you are using to access Cloudwatch:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:<region-code>:<youraccount>:log-group:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:<region-code>:<youraccount>:log-group:<loggroup-name>:log-stream:"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:<region-code>:<youraccount>:log-group:<loggroup-name>:log-stream:<logstream-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

And you are ready to log to CloudWatch.
I do not know why this feature is not described in the official documentation.

Last but not least, if you are using React Native like me, you will not have `util` package and `TextExncoder()` utility. For me it was enought to install a polyfill like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder):

```
npm install fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder
```

and import it as the first line in my index.js:

```
import 'fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder';
```

Comment: I don't see it very useful. I want to see any console output of my application. Specifically made with console.log and console.error. Or basically stdoutput and stderror. Obviously not only what I sent to CloudWatch using some custom functions after a lot of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

*Hi all, I see this is an older question and just thought I would provide an answer to assist with anyone who is directed here (with similar questions, specifically in regards to the Amplify utility - Logger) The question appears to be referring more towards logging for historical reasons as opposed to the Logger which logs to the console window and the answer is probably not what the questioner requires, however the question itself could bring a number of people here looking for answers on how to use the Amplify Logger or where to find its output. If so I hope this helps.*

**Amplify Logger**

The simple answer to the question

> Where to find AWS Amplify Logger logs

is that Amplify Logger outputs content directly to your web browser console window.

**More Details**

The Amplify Logger utility logs content to the browser console. While developing your app you can set the global log level of your browser console by typing the following (into your console) or you can set it directly in your code:

```
window.LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO';
```

You have several log levels you can choose from including **DEBUG**, **INFO**, **WARN**, **ERROR** and **VERBOSE**.

When you call Logger from your code:

```
logger.info(`user has signed in with ${username}`);
```

and have set the appropriate log level, you should see the output (in your console):

```
[INFO] 20:09.950 YourLoggerName - user has signed in with johndoe@example.com
```

And just for completeness, this is how to use Amplify Logger in an App:

```
import { Logger } from 'aws-amplify';

const logger = new Logger('YourLoggerName');

const exampleSignIn = () => {
    const { username, password } = inputs;
    logger.info(`user signing in with ${username}`);
    Auth.signIn(username, password)
        .then(user => signInSuccess(user))
        .catch(err => signInError(err));
}

const signInError = (err) => {
    logger.error('error signing in', err); 
    // more code
}
```

There are a few more options and ways to use it, as described in the documentation linked in the question, such as setting logging levels etc.

Here is that link again:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/logger/q/platform/js

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well; I'm frankly new with lambda/serverless, but needed to deploy a very simple API endpoint in node.js via Amplify. Note that what I'm describing is for a Backend environment, that is, code which runs serverless, not connected to your browser (previous answer mentions "Amplify Logger outputs content directly to your web browser console window" - that's not what I'm talking about here).

The directions previously given about Cloudwatch are correct but insufficient; I could not find the "log group" corresponding to my amplify app.  It took considerable hunting through the AWS console to find a direct link to my logs -- and I discovered I could not find the corresponding log group through the Cloud Watch panel.

Ultimately I found joy via the following path starting from the Amplify console:

1. Go to my app
2. Chose Backend environments "tab" (I have no Hosting environments so this happens automatically for me)
3. Click on Functions (under Categories added)
4. Here you see a window which purports to show logs.  Hah!
5. Click "View in CloudWatch" link above this blank "log" window

This gets me to the relevant log group, where I can see my log streams and "tail."

Note that I am able to see what I'm logging in my node.js with simple console.log() calls.  I did not set up any of the additional configuration described in other answers (but it's probable that I'm executing my code with a role which already has the required permissions which are explicitly recommended, you may not be so lucky).

Answer (score 0):

There is this solution:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/8309

Even though this pull request was merged and some people claim to have it working. I personally ran into permission trouble and this "feature" isn't named anywhere in the docs of the amplify.aws website.