# Amplify hosting logging with console.log server side

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-amplify

Can somebody provide clean instruction how to show logs from `console.log` in amplify hosting. I understand it's possible even for the client side logs, but definitely I would like to see server side logs.

I mean at the moment I see only messages like there was a request and a response in the CloudWatch that is more like access logs. I've seen this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/74754749/5177149 . I had continues errors trying to follow it like "Can't read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')". And either it is not actual any more or I miss some important steps. Also it uses a special class for logging and this is not convenient at all: while I can use some other functions for logging in my own code, but other components use `console.log` and `console.error`.

I would like to have simple logging like the default behaviour in kubernetes containers when you can see in the logs everything from the standard application output. At the moment I'm completely blind and can't understand why my applications work not as well as locally after deploying. I spend hours and days trying to understand what is the error and it's a compeltly stupid situation for the hosting. I couldn't find working instruction how to setup this obvious feature: just to have logs.